# JavaScript минифицированный файл

Tags: javascript, jquery

Дали сайт, чтобы поправил и добавил к слайдеру фоток слайдшоу, но файл с кодом оказался минифицированный, и разобраться в нем нереально.

Подскажите что делать?

Comment: Затребовать нормальные исходники. Если не дадут, требовать сроки/бюджет в 2-3 раза больше

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй сервис jsbeautifier.org.

Я сам сталкивался с проблемой преобразования минифицированного js в читабельный вид. И этот сервис мне очень помог. Он прост и удобен в использовании.

Answer (score 1):

Если скрипт их, то просишь нормальный исходник.

Если в скрипте есть ссылка на сайт разработчика (или на страницу на github'е), идёшь туда и смотришь код.

Если нужно отлаживать минифицированный скрипт, жмёшь кнопку автоформатирования в Хроме или IE и отлаживаешь. У IE есть плюс, что он объявление каждой переменной и записанные через запятую top-level-операции считает отдельными statement'ами при отладке.